# Pack nuspec file during build in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, .net-core, nuspec

I have a VS2017 solution with multiple projects that generates a cross-platform nuget-package. The package is generated by running nuget pack on my specific nuspec file. I would like to automatically performs this action during Visual Studio build instead of doing it manually each time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pack nuspec file during build in Visual Studio. Is this possible?

The answer is yes. You can simple add a pro-build or post-build event (`Project->properties->Build Events`) to generate nuget package with below command line:

```
nuget.exe pack "$(ThePathOfYour .nuspec)\TestPackNupsec.csproj.nuspec"
```

Note: You should add the `nuget.exe` as a system variable, so that you can use it anywhere without specifying the specific path of nuget, or you need specify the full path of nuget in that command line, like:

`C:\Users\<UserName>\nuget.exe`

With this command line in the build-event, we could generate Pack nuspec file during build in Visual Studio:

[image]